# How to replace a value for a particular key in List[Row] in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

New to Scala !! I have a `List[Row]` where `Row` is `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` and it has something like

```
val list =  List("""{"name":"abc","salary":"somenumber","id":"1"}"""")
```

How do  I replace the key salary with something else ?

Comment: You can try the for comprehension or map.

Comment: It is . I can convert it into a dataframe and then use collect and then transform it into a List[Row]. How to replace the value after that ? @RameshMaharjan

Comment: Let me try @Sid

Comment: The problem is I don't want to do it with a dataframe. I want to do it with List[Row]

Comment: Yeah. LIke, i want to get the key 'salary' and want to replace that with something else

Comment: Yeah it should be something like {"name":"abc","salary":"new_salary","id":"1"}

Comment: I would suggest you to go with dataframe and save your time

Comment: I am not supposed to use that. Its a module where I have got to work with List[Row]. So I am just using DataFrame for testing.

Comment: you can do something like `list.map(row => Row.fromSeq(Seq(row.getAs[String]("name"), row.getAs[String]("id"), "new_salary")))` which should be `res0: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = List([abc,1,new_salary])`

Comment: there is no getAs method available @RameshMaharjan

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below solution. I hope, It will help you

If your input is like below

```
scala>  val list = List("""{"name":"abc","salary":"somenumber","id":"1"}""")
list: List[String] = List({"name":"abc","salary":"somenumber","id":"1"})
```

I am converting `List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` to `List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]`

```
scala> val listOfMaps=list.map(Row=>Row(0).toString.replaceAll("[{}]","").split(",").map(str=>(str.split(":")(0),str.split(":")(1))).toMap)
listOfMaps: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = List(Map(name -> abc, salary -> somenumber, id -> 1"))
```

Since, I can't update the value of `immutable` map to converting it to `mutable` map and updating value

```
import collection.mutable.Map
scala> val mutableMap=listOfMaps.map(mp=>collection.mutable.Map(mp.toSeq: _*)).map(mp=>mp+("\""+"salary"+"\""->"2000"))
mutableMap: List[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]] = List(Map(name -> abc, salary -> 2000, id -> 1"))
```

Getting output in original format that `List[Row]`

```
scala> val ans=mutableMap.map(mp=>Row("{"+mp.mkString(",").replaceAll("->",":")+"}"))
ans: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = List([{name : abc,salary : 2000,id : 1"}])
```

Comment: Thank you. But why does 

val listOfMaps=list.map(Row=>Row(0).toString.replaceAll("[{}]","").split(",").map(str=>(str.split(":")(0),str.split(":")(1))).toMap) 

give me an ArrayOutOfBoundIndexException for the index 1

Comment: @JayVignesh Are you writing the same code as I wrote? Or you changed input?

Comment: I am writing your code. And my input is val list = List("""{"name":"abc","salary":"somenumber","id":"1"}""") . The only difference is I have added a " " for all the keys and values

Comment: @JayVignesh Your input is just List[String] , Please make it List[Row]  like this
val list = List(Row("""{"name":"abc","salary":"somenumber","id":"1"}"""))

Comment: I have made that List[String] to List[Row] using val collected = list.map(x => Row.fromSeq(Seq(x))) . Is this okay ?

Comment: Then replace list from collected in this like below - val listOfMaps=collected.map(Row=>Row(0).toString.replaceAll("[{}]","").split(",").map(str=>(str.split(":")(0),str.split(":")(1))).toMap)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173294/discussion-between-manoj-kumar-dhakd-and-jay-vignesh).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to maintain data in spark SQL rows, then you can perform the groupBy operation in spark itself. see below taken from [How to calculate sum and count in a single groupBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449139/how-to-calculate-sum-and-count-in-a-single-groupby)

```
// In 1.3.x, in order for the grouping column "department" to show up, 
// it must be included explicitly as part of the agg function call. 
df.groupBy("department").agg($"department", max("age"), sum("expense"))

// In 1.4+, grouping column "department" is included automatically. 
df.groupBy("department").agg(max("age"), sum("expense"))
```

feel free to vote on the close duplicate, placing it here until decision is made.

Comment: Yeah this can be done when I use operations with DataFrame. But as I said before, I want to deal with List[Row]. But, Appreciate the help

Comment: are you trying to use the same query to have the aggregate and detailed data, is that why you have this requirement? try to measure the timing on using single query vs using two queries.